# I don't know why only lambda function can run when I use GUI Button command

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, lambda

```py
def btn_click(btn):
    global expression
    expression = expression + str(btn)
    btn_input.set(expression)


btn_7= Button(root, text = '7', width =5, height =2, command=lambda:btn_click(7))
# btn_7= Button(root, text = '7', width =5, height =2, command=btn_click(7))
```

So Can I know reason and principle about this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may run normal functions via this 'command' argument, but the point here is that you won't be able to pass arguments to the function

```py
def func():
    print('click')
button = Button(root, text = '7', width =5, height =2, command=func)
# If you run this and click the button you'll see 'click' message in the console
```

But let's say that you need to pass argument to your function, for example number of button you clicked. In this case you need to use lambda function

```py
def func(num):
    print(num)
button = Button(root, text = '7', width =5, height =2, command=lambda: func(7))
```

When you do it this way happens this:
When button clicked, TKinter calls this lambda function, and then lambda function calls your func() with argument '7'

Answer (score 1):

This is common when you need to pass both a function AND its argument to something only expecting a function.

In your second example, `command=btn_click(7)` will call `btn_click(7)` and pass the results to `command`, which by its name is looking to take a callable (function).

If you wrap your function call in a lambda, you are then passing an unnamed callable to `command` which, when called, evaluates `btn_click(7)`.